# Can @RequestMapping in Springboot be omitted?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to make the method name be the 'value' of @RequestMapping.

That means how to make the code1 be the code2?

```java
//Code1
 @RequestMapping("hello")
 public Object hello() {
//...
}
```

```java
//Code2
 public Object hello() {
//...
}
```

-----add more to make it clear ---2019-2-27 15:47:50
TO make it clear, I want to get two API user/hello, user/bye by code:

````java
@RestController
    @RequestMapping(value="/user")
    public class UserController {

        //no requestmapping annotation here, that is what I say 'omitted'
        public object hello() { 
           // your code 
        }

        //no requestmapping annotation here
        public object bye() { 
         // your code 
        }
        ```
````

Comment: You can define the RequestMapping at class level and use just GetMapping at the method level. This way you don't need to define the path in the method level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have one common URL in your request.
Let's say you have /user in your all requests then instead of your writing /user in all your method, you can use @RequestMapping(value="/user") as below. You can have multiple methods inside your controller

```
    @RestController
    public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/user/hello",method=RequestMethod.yourMethod)
    public object hello() { // your code 

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/user/bye",method=RequestMethod.yourMethod)
    public object bye() { // your code 

    }
```

Solution:

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value="/user")
    public class UserController {

        @RequestMapping(value="/hello",method=RequestMethod.yourMethod)
        public object hello() { // your code 

        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/bye",method=RequestMethod.yourMethod)
        public object bye() { // your code 

        }
```

Comment: Does that mean only one Method  can be in a Controller?

Comment: see the update. If you are satisfied with an answer you can accept it or can ask if you have any doubt

Comment: So that I get two API, /user/hello, /user/bye, with annotion on every method ?

Comment: user/hello will execute hello() and user/bye will execute bye() method. what do you mean by an annotation on every method?

Comment: What I want to get is the same API but code is  
```java
@RestController
    @RequestMapping(value="/user")
    public class UserController {

        public object hello() { // your code 

        }

        public object bye() { // your code 

        }
  ```

Comment: @KiwiQi spring boot application will start even if you do not specify the request mapping before a method and even you can specify multiple URL in one RequestMapping but the point is how spring will get to know which method to execute on a user requested URL. so whatever you are trying to do is not a good practice

Comment: Thank you so much. RequestMap is used to distinguish between java method and URL method, Is there any mistake in my understanding?

Comment: @KiwiQi RequestMapping Annotation is used for mapping web requests onto methods in request-handling classes with flexible method signatures.